# Passport Login Proplem _login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, passport.js

On my signup form page for my react passport app on the submission it gives me an error this.props._login() is not a function.

I've tried changing _login to login and getting rid of props

```
class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            redirectTo: null
        }
        // this.googleSignin = this.googleSignin.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        console.log('handleSubmit')
        this.props._login(this.state.username, this.state.password)
        this.setState({
            redirectTo: '/'
        })
    }
```

Comment: You don't have function `_login`

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor you're only setting the default state:

```
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        redirectTo: null
    }
    // ...
}
```

But you never *read* the passed props as the first parameter, and so your `this.props` value is never defined.

You must forward the first parameter of the constructor to `super()` like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        username: '',
        password: '',
        redirectTo: null
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I forgot props!

Comment: @max If this answer solved your issue, you can mark it as 'accepted' to notify other users/the system about it.